# EE vs Drupal: structuring the abstract concept of 'content'

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, content-management-system, expressionengine

I understand (and love) Drupal's approach of using Content Types and Fields to create a representation of the structure of any content.  And it looks like EE uses Channels & Fields in pursuit of the same goal.  Given their similarities, and my background with Drupal, I'm having a little trouble clearly seeing the differences.

What are the important similarities and differences between Drupal and ExpressionEngine when it comes to how they capture and structure content?

Comment: Jack if you don't get the response you are looking for here I'd recommend heading over to the dedicated EE stack: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks, I didn't see that